# Limiting CSS styles to one page/view using Bootstrap gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Using the bootstrap-sass gem, how can I limit the styles to one page/view?

For example, I built an app using the gem, and everything works fine. I created a test view, and added code for a Bootstrap cover page ([link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/)).  To get the correct styles to work I imported the cover.css file into my assets and called it in application.scss like so:

```
@import "cover";
```

However the effect this had is that it's global and all my views look like this. How do you limit the style to something like index.html.erb?

Comment: You could just move the import to a single .scss file that is only included by the one view.  You don't have to put all the stylesheets in the main application one.  So instead of importing into application.scss, import into cover.scss and include that scss directly in the view.

Comment: OK, I follow, but one thing I'm not clear on is how do you call it directly into the view.  Instinct says something like `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>` but how do you call cover.scss?

Comment: Just repeat that line with cover.scss.  I'll write a more complete answer shortly, but you're almost there.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.

Based on your comment, you likely have an `.../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` that includes the line `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>`.  That's good, because it likely covers all your pages for common styles (since the layout view provides the base template).   Alternatively, that line can appear in each of your pages if they don't have a common layout, but that's usually less DRY.

To limit a style, make a separate `cover_set.scss` with the single line `@import "cover";` like you suggested in your OP.  (There are other ways, but this way is sure to pull in the `.scss`.  You could just directly use the original `cover.scss` if you don't want or need the partial formulation.)

Then in the view(s) you want to apply that style, use the following snippet:

```
<% content_for :header do -%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'cover_set', media: 'all' %>
<% end -%>
```

If you want to just use the original `cover.scss` directly, then just use `cover` instead of `cover_set` above.

The `content_for` structure works for javascripts and anything else that you want put into the `<HEAD>` tag.

Comment: I feel like I'm close but not quite there.  I left all the common `@import` in `application.scss` and created a new `cover.scss` in `...app/assets/stylesheets` with the lone `@import "cover";`  I then added `<% content_for :header do -%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'cover', media: 'all' %>
<% end -%>`  to the one view, `index.html.erb` ,where I want this style to apply.  The other views I left alone, but when I call `index.html.erb`, I receive an error that cover is calling (or looping onto) itself.  All the other views are rendering correctly (with Bootstrap).

Comment: I tried to make it clear but the internal one and external one can't be named the same.   If you follow the example I offered, see that I used 'cover_set', not 'cover' for the "external" one.   There is a simpler version, but it's a little different.   Do you want me to update the answer to make this more clear?

Comment: No, I understand.  I actually tried that earlier, I'm just limited in my answer.  I renamed the scss, `cover_set.scss`, and changed the top of `index.html.erb` to `<% content_for :header do -%> <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'cover_set', media: 'all' %> <% end -%>` just as you mentioned.  The error changed to, "Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( cover_set.css )` to assets.rb, and restart the server". Did that, and now it runs, but its not rendering with "cover" styles, just plain Bootstrap. Viewing the source, I see it found `application.scss` but not `cover_set`.

Comment: So if I understand, the asset pipeline is now creating cover_set.css and it is found as a peer in the same directory as application.css, correct?  If so, then the issue appears to be in how we're including it in the view.  To check that, I'd use the browser to do either a view source or inspect elements (developer tools) and see what HTML was produced to verify a line got into the header.

Comment: Ok. I'll delve into it.  Thank you for all your help. Hopefully in a couple hours Ill have a comment saying, "Where I screwed up was..."  Followed by, "I fixed it by..."

Comment: @Macniaco Feel free to let me know if you're still having problems with this.  Good luck!